# Related list visibility

Tags: profile

I record meetings and emails etc against my accounts in Salesforce. Is it possible to create a profile that can see the related list entries, but not the actual content of the related list?

I want the employees to be able to see and click into their own and their group's entries, but not those of another group.

I assume this is possible using profiles, but I cannot think how I can create a profile that makes things available depending on groups?
Tks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is to use organization wide sharing and sharing rules which open access to specific groups. You can read more about those options [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_owd_about.htm&language=en_US). This way, someone could see the related list but would not be able to see actual records in it unless they have been given permissions through the sharing rules.